# Why does my app crashes with Admob and Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I pubblished an app on google play. Then I linked it to Admob and the app works, showing me the banner of admob. Sometimes, on launch, it crashes, sometimes not. I viewed Android Studio Logcat and this is the error. Can someone help me?

```
Process: it.bluebait.mycurrency, PID: 13200
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at lt.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
        at ls.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1)
        at lu.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10)
        at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7)
        at kx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001f/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_30000000.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001f/n/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ac.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@16089081@16.0.89 (100400-239467275):4)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at lt.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2) 
        at ls.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1) 
        at lu.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10) 
        at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7) 
        at kx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2) 
2019-04-09 19:43:27.941 15295-15544/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
    Process: it.bluebait.mycurrency, PID: 15295
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at lt.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
        at ls.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1)
        at lu.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10)
        at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7)
        at kx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001f/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_30000000.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001f/n/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ac.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@16089081@16.0.89 (100400-239467275):4)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at lt.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2) 
        at ls.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1) 
        at lu.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10) 
        at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7) 
        at kx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2) 
2019-04-09 19:43:27.953 563-563/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for service=opdiagnose pid=15295 uid=10236 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c236,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:opdiagnose_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2019-04-09 19:43:27.956 563-563/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for service=opdiagnose pid=15295 uid=10236 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c236,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:opdiagnose_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android 9.0 finally removed by default all traces of the old Apache HTTP library. However it seems that some libraries need it. You need to add this to your manifest inside the `<application>` element:

```
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false"/>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Comment: Official support thread - they recommend this workaround as well: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/K1HKru7RutY/VEr-Qm00BwAJ

Answer (score -3):

i Suggest updating you update the dependencies to the latest versions.
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'